# Where Does LAB.js Keep Coming From In Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

I keep seeing an error in the JS console in safari, it seems to happen all over the place and not just on code i am writing. At the moment i see it on some code i have been writing but i never have included LAB.js in the code, so where is it coming from? Why is it showing the following error in the console if i have never even tried to use it?

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '/^[^?#]*\//.exec(location.href)[0]')
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I tested as Merlin advised ... for me it was an extension related to iTube Studio 6.1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by an `extension`. Disable extensions one by one to see which one is causing the problem.